# Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript, imagick, php-7.4

I want to convert pdf file to jpg. I installed ***imagick*** correctly and I installed ***ghoscript 9.53.3 64x*** but I got this error. I put the ghoscript / bin and lib path in the enviroment variable.

> Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified. ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/794 in C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\kOnline\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-image\src\Pdf.php:40 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\kOnline\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-image\src\Pdf.php(40): Imagick->pingimage('C:/xampp7.4/htd...') #1 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\kOnline\pdfToImaage.php(8): Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf->__construct('C:/xampp7.4/htd...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\kOnline\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-image\src\Pdf.php on line 40

my code:

```
$pdf = new Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf($pathToPdf);


foreach (range(1, $pdf->getNumberOfPages()) as $pageNumber) {

    $pdf->setPage($pageNumber);

    $pdf->saveImage("Image_name".$pageNumber.".png");
}
```

**PHP Version 7.4.11**

**Apache Version    Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11**

**ghoscript 9.53.3 64x**

**imagick module version    3.4.4**

**OS windows 10 64x**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I uninstalled `ghoscript 9.53.3` and installed `ghoscript 9.26`. I restarted the system after installation.  That's all and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 5):

I am using `gs9.54.0`

Adding ghostscript path to the `PATH`, in my case `c:\softkit\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\` and rename `gswin64.exe` to `gs.exe` solved this issue.

It seems indeed that `imagick` is looking for `gs.exe`

Comment: working for me.. i using gs 9.55 version

Answer (score 4):

1- Download from the site:
https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html
if php 7.3: php_imagick-3.6.0-7.3-ts-vc15-x64.zip
if php 7.4: php_imagick-3.6.0-7.4-ts-vc15-x64.zip
if php 8.0: php_imagick-3.6.0-8.0-ts-vs16-x64.zip

2- Unzip the one that corresponds to the PHP version
A- take the DLL which is called: php_imagick.dll
and place it in the directory C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.3.23-Win32-VC15-x64/ext
B- take all the other DLLs and put them in the directory C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.3.23-Win32-VC15-x64

3- Open the PHP.ini file and insert the line where there are
The extensions precisely and write there:
extension = php_imagick.dll

4- Stop the APACH server and do a phpinfo(); to see
if the library is correctly installed with all
extensions possible

//////////////////////////
If you want to handle the PDFs from imagick continue the steps following
//////////////////////////

5- Then, you have to install the ghoscript software from
following url: https://www.ghostscript.com/releases/gsdnld.html
install the version that is going well x64 bit for example

6- Then, go to the directory
C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.55.0/bin
A- Duplicate the gswin64.exe file
B- Rename the copy to gs.exe

7- Add the directory C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.55.0/bin
in the PATH environment variables (users)
To do this, go to SEARCH WINDOWS and type env + enter
after go to environment variables and add
the missing directory

8- Super important, close the LARAGON software (completely)
Then turn it back on LARAGON and at this time, everything should function

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem.
In older versions of ghostscript the executable was named "gs.exe", in newer versions it's "gswin32c.exe" (or "gswin64c.exe"). I think somewhere the gs.exe-call is hard coded into the imagick-extension.
As workaround just rename the file to "gs.exe" or put a renamed copy in this directory.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the version provided in [this link](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html)

And I had to downgrade my ghostscript to [v5.26](https://www.npackd.org/p/com.ghostscript.Ghostscript64/9.25) and it worked. With the latest version of GS the server didn't response.

Also you have to:

1. copy `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.25\bin\gswin64.exe`
2. Rename to `gs.exe`
3. Add `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.25\bin` to the environment variable `PATH` (maybe the installation path is other in your system).