# PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified. ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/794

Tags: php, laravel, imagick

I'm using the laravel spatie package to convert pdfs to images and he works just fine until I decided to upgrade to php8 so I uninstalled & reinstalled xampp with php8
after that, I installed Imgaick and restarts the server, when I tried to upload a pdf the server caused this error:

> PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified. ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/794

So I decided to return to php7 the error still acquiring.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: why the error(PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified. ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/794)  still acquiring, even when I'm using the old environment that is used to work (xampp,image magick, ghostscript, image magick php extension used to work tegother, now they dont')

Comment: Have you tried to look for other solutions on SO? like https://stackoverflow.com/a/65718606/3160483

Comment: yes I tried, I installed 4 versions of GS, 9.54.0, 9.53.3, 9.53.2,  9.53.1, the problem is that the version 9.53.3 used to work before I upgraded to php8

Answer (score 0):

solved for me, I'm not sure how, I just commented out://Ghostscript::setGsPath('C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\bin\gs.exe');
and made GhostScript accessible through the environment variables